# A harmonic function degenerate in one direction

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, harmonic-functions

**Question.** Let $u: B^3 \to \mathbf{R}$ be a harmonic function with $u(0) = 0$, $Du(0) = 0$, where its homogeneous harmonic blow-up is a polynomial $p = p(x,y)$ in two variables, so independent of $z$; in other words $p$ is a non-zero homogeneous harmonic polynomial so that
\begin{equation}
u(x,y,z) = p(x,y) + o( \lvert (x,y,z) \rvert^m),
\end{equation}
where $2 \leq m = \operatorname{deg} p$. Must $u$ be translation-invariant with respect to $z$? Can the origin be isolated in the singular set $u^{-1}(0) \cap \lvert Du \rvert^{-1}(0)$?

Comment: Could you define the homogenuous harmonic blow-up?

Comment: The answer to the first question is negative: a counterexample is $u(x,y,x)=P_m(x,y)+Q_n(x,y,z),$ where $P_m,P_n$ are homogeneous harmonic polynomials of degrees $n>m$, and $P_n$ depends on all three variables.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Of course, how embarrassing that I missed that - thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune Here I meant the limit as $r \to 0$ of the functions $x \in B_1 \mapsto \lvert u (r \cdot) \rvert_{L^2(\partial B_1)}^{-1} u(rx)$, so the rescaling by the $L^2$-norm. Sorry it took me so long to reply to your comment - as I was typing it, Alexandre's comment popped up.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune I guess you can basically think of it as the lowest-order (non-zero) homogeneous harmonic polynomial $p$ so that $u = p + o(\lvert x \rvert^m)$, where $m$ is the degree of $p$. If I am not mistaken the tricky point is to show that this polynomial exists at all, which you do via monotonicity of the frequency functional. (This whole viewpoint makes Alexandre's comment all the more natural.) I'll edit the question to make this point a bit less opaque.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Never mind, I think you can just take a linear combination of two homogeneous polynomials $P_m + \delta Q_n$ and take $\delta > 0$ small enough that no additional singular points are created. I worked out an example, see the most recent edit.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko By the way, if you wanted to post your comments as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it!

Comment: @Leo Moos: My second comment was not correct, and I deleted it. Anyway, you solved the problem yourself, probably inspired by the first (trivial) comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The questions have been answered in the comments, I am just recording them here: Alexandre Eremenko pointed out that *no*, the function $u$ need not be translation-invariant, because the dependencies on $z$ could be 'hidden' inside a polynomial of higher degree, say
\begin{equation}
u = p(x,y) + q(x,y,z),
\end{equation}
with $\operatorname{deg} q > \operatorname{deg} p$.

This also gives a hint for the second question: the answer is *yes*, there exist examples of such $u$ that only have isolated singularity at the origin. The example given below $u$ is basically of the form above—with $q$ picked so as to have an isolated singularity at the origin—, except for the fact that one multiplies $q$ by a small constant to avoid introducing new singular points.

Specifically, pick a constant $\delta \in (0,1/3)$ and define
\begin{equation}
u(x,y,z) = x^2 - y^2 + \delta(2x^3 - 3xy^2 - 3xz^2).
\end{equation}
Then
\begin{equation}
Du(x,y,z) = (2x + \delta( 6x^2 - 3y^2 - 3z^2),-2y - 6\delta xy,-6\delta xz).
\end{equation}
At a critical point $(x,y,z)$:

- from $D_y u = 0$ one finds that $y(1 + 3\delta x) = 0$. As $\delta < 3$, the second factor never vanishes if $\lvert x \rvert < 1$, so $y = 0$;
- from $D_z u = 0$ one finds that either $x = 0$ or $z = 0$.
- from $D_x u = 0$, if $x = 0$ then immediately $z = 0$. If instead $z = 0$ then $0 = D_x u = 2x + 6\delta x^2 = 2x(1 + 3 \delta x)$. Again, our choice of a sufficiently small $\delta$ means that $1 + 3 \delta x > 0$ on $B^3$, so $x = 0$.

Therefore $Du(x,y,z) = 0$ is equivalent to $(x,y,z) = 0$. Obviously $u(0,0,0) = 0$, so this is indeed the unique singular point.